# How to copy matching files from directory/subdirectory to a another directory

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, cp

I am having following folder structure.

```
applications (main directory)
  - 1 (sub directory)
    application_1.pdf
  - 2 
    application_2.pdf
  - 3
    application_3.pdf
```

I wanted to copy all the `application_*.pdf` pattern files to a single directory. How to achieve that with shell script?

so far I have tried following but it copies all the subdirectories as well

```
cp -r "$path_src/" "$path_dst/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp applications/*/application_*.pdf /destination/path/
```

This would copy all the PDF files matching `application_*.pdf` in any subdirectory of `applications` into `/destination/path/`.  This relies on all PDF files having unique names (as to not "collide" in the destination directory).